# React: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression | Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1,

Tags: reactjs

first, im new in react and js;
second, I have a broke english(sorry);
third, Im trying read one array of the hours of the days, The function HoursOfTheDay() runs more then perfect in console.log, but im having a bad time trying print on the screen.
When I try use the .map, show a error:  " `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`", and when I try without show a "`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys{0,1...`", so I know that have something there, but i dont know how to print it out.
Im stuck with that, I`m imploring for help!!!!!!!!!!
thank you for your time btw.

the error its this little shit `{this.HoursOfTheDay().map((hour,i)=> {<div key={i}>{hour}</div>})}`

**
class Hour extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        schedule: null,
        hours: null
    };
}
//My day`s hour component
HoursOfTheDay() {
    var date = this.props.schedule.date;
    var start = new Date(date);
    var end = new Date(date); end.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    
    var todayhours = {};
    var count = 0;

    while (end >= start) {
        start = new Date(start.getTime() + (0.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        todayhours[count] = start;
        count++;
    }
    return todayhours;
}

render() {
    const { schedule } = this.props;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className={classes.div}>

            <TableContainer className={classes.tablecontainer} component={Paper}>
                <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="set a hour">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            {...}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>

                        <TableRow >    
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                            <div>
                            //The fuck thing that don`t work
                            {this.HoursOfTheDay().map((hour,i)=> {
                                <div key={i}>{hour}</div>
                            })}
                            </div>
                        </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>

                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </div>
    );
};
```

}
**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CalendarSchedule  from './schedule/calendarschedule';
import Hour from './schedule/Hour';

class quote extends Component {


  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      schedule: {
        date: new Date().toDateString(),
        hours: null
      }
      };
  }


  getSchedule = event =>{
  let newSchedule = {date: event.toDateString()};
  this.setState({schedule : newSchedule }, () => {
      console.log("insert",this.state.schedule);
    }); 
  };


  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

      return (
        <div className={classes.div}>
          <div>
            //lib react-calendar
            <CalendarSchedule
              sendSchedule={this.getSchedule.bind(this)}
              {...this.stateschedule}/>
          </div>
            
          <div>
            //My component problem
            <div >       
              <Hour schedule={this.state.schedule} />
            </div>             
          </div>

        </div>
    
      );
  }
}

export default quote;
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`todayHours` is an object and you're using `.map` which doesn't exist.
You can use `Object.values` to convert your object's values in an array.

More on [Object.values here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        schedule: null,
        hours: null
    };
}
//My day`s hour component
HoursOfTheDay() {
    var date = this.props.schedule.date;
    var start = new Date(date);
    var end = new Date(date); end.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    
    var todayhours = {};
    var count = 0;

    while (end >= start) {
        start = new Date(start.getTime() + (0.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        todayhours[count] = start;
        count++;
    }
    return todayhours;
}

render() {
    const { schedule } = this.props;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <div className={classes.div}>

            <TableContainer className={classes.tablecontainer} component={Paper}>
                <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="set a hour">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            {...}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>

                        <TableRow >    
                        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                            <div>
                            // now it should work
                            {Object.values(this.HoursOfTheDay()).map((hour,i)=> {
                                <div key={i}>{hour}</div>
                            })}
                            </div>
                        </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>

                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: And try not to curse or use inappropriate words here. People might downvote you. And chances are, no one would answer your question.